# MySQL: LOAD DATA INFILE syntax error 1064

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I am trying to use LOAD DATA INFILE in MySQL like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE ‘mfsw_test.csv’ 
REPLACE INTO TABLE mfsw_curr 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘,’ 
LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\n’ 
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

I am getting an error:

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '‘mfsw_test.txt’ 
REPLACE INTO TABLE mfsw_curr FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘,’ LI' at line 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try replacing ‘ with '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your quotes.  the single quote should be a basic `'` not the word-ified smartquote `‘’`